# Why does the engine of some cars idle faster when the car is moving?

Tags: idle

**This is not a defect.** It is a feature implemented on purpose. I've driven other cars that did the same thing. When in neutral, the idle speed changes from 750 rpm to 900 rpm when the car starts moving. The opposite is also true: when in neutral, the idle goes from 900 rpm to 750 rpm when the car is stopped. If the car is stopped (and the engine is hot), the idle is always 750 rpm and does not change. If the car is moving, even on highways, the idle at neutral is always 900 rpm. My car is a manual. So, there is an "idle speed correction" if the car is moving. However, I can't understand the reason this feature was implemented and why is it useful or important somehow.

Comment: I have driven cars that don’t do that... but I do note that the use of ac will cause an increase in idle if the compressor has to work.

Comment: The majority of the cars actually don't do that. But in this case, it is really speed-related, not any other additional load on the car.